# Importing a JLabel array into a JComponent

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlabel, jcomponent

I looked around trying to resolve my issue but could not find anything to resolve this. I am really new to java and am trying to do projects from the book without using the console but here is what I have,

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class FutureInvestmentValue {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double investmentAmount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter in the investment amount as a double.", "Investment Amout",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE));

    double monthlyInterestRate = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter in the monthly interest rate as a double.", "Monthly Interest Rate",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE));

    int years = 30;

    final JComponent[] outputHeader = new JComponent[] {
            new JLabel("The amount invested: " + investmentAmount),
            new JLabel("Annual interest Rate: " + monthlyInterestRate),
            new JLabel("Years       Future Value"),
    };


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputHeader + futureInvestmentValue(investmentAmount, monthlyInterestRate, years), "Future Investment Value",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}

public static JComponent[] futureInvestmentValue(double investmentAmount, double monthlyInterestRate, int years) {
    final JComponent[] investmentArray = new JComponent[years];
    for (int i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
        double investmentTotal = investmentAmount + (investmentAmount * ((monthlyInterestRate / 10) * i));
        investmentArray[i] = new JLabel(i + "              " + investmentTotal);
    }

return investmentArray;
}
}
```

and it seems that I am getting errors that are telling to to change futureInvestmentValue(); to a Jcomponent and when I do that another error happens and it just runs me in circles with changing from JLabel to JLabel[] to Jcomponent to Jcomponent[] and what not. Any help that can explain it to me in terms that wouldnt be confusing to a newbie would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

- why do you create an array of JLabel, to use the JTable instead,

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ChangeNotifiersOnEvent extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean runProcess = true;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private javax.swing.Timer timerRun;
    private Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private String[] columnNames = {"Source", "Hit", "Last", "Ur_Diff"};
    private JTable table;
    private Object[][] data = {{"Swing Timer", 2.99, 5, 1.01},
        {"Swing Worker", 7.10, 5, 1.010}, {"TableModelListener", 25.05, 5, 1.01}};
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

    public ChangeNotifiersOnEvent() {
        table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent tme) {
                if (tme.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
                    if (tme.getColumn() == 1 && tme.getLastRow() == 2) {
                        double dbl = ((Double) table.getModel().getValueAt(2, 1))
                                - ((Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(2, 2));
                        table.getModel().setValueAt(dbl, 2, 3);
                    } else if (tme.getColumn() == 1 && tme.getLastRow() == 0) {
                        prepareUpdateTableCell();
                    } else if (tme.getColumn() == 1 && tme.getLastRow() == 1) {
                        executor.execute(new MyTask(MyTask.UPDATE_TABLE_COLUMN));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        table.setRowHeight(30);
        table.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(180);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    private void prepareUpdateTableCell() {
        timerRun = new javax.swing.Timer(10, UpdateTableCell());
        timerRun.setRepeats(false);
        timerRun.start();
    }

    private Action UpdateTableCell() {
        return new AbstractAction("Update Table Cell") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                double dbl = ((Double) table.getModel().getValueAt(0, 1))
                        - ((Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(0, 2));
                table.getModel().setValueAt(dbl, 0, 3);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (runProcess) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(330);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            changeTableValues();
        }
    }

    private void changeTableValues() {
        Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(128) + random.nextDouble(), 0, 1);
                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(256) + random.nextDouble(), 1, 1);
                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(512) + random.nextDouble(), 2, 1);

                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(128), 0, 2);
                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(128), 1, 2);
                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(128), 2, 2);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
    }

    private class MyTask extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {

        private static final String UPDATE_TABLE_COLUMN = "update";
        private String namePr;
        private double dbl;

        MyTask(String str) {
            this.namePr = str;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            dbl = ((Double) table.getModel().getValueAt(1, 1))
                    - ((Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(1, 2));
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    table.getModel().setValueAt(dbl, 1, 3);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ChangeNotifiersOnEvent frame = new ChangeNotifiersOnEvent();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocation(150, 150);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

- you can to add / remove row(s) on runtime,

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class RemoveAddRows extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Object[] columnNames = {"Type", "Company", "Shares", "Price"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50)},
        {"Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25)},
        {"Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35)},
        {"Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00)}
    };
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;

    public RemoveAddRows() {

        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                int firstRow = 0;
                int lastRow = table.getRowCount() - 1;
                int width = 0;
                if (row == lastRow) {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (row == firstRow) {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(Color.blue);
                } else {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(table.getBackground());
                }
                /*if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
                String type = (String) getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
                c.setBackground("Buy".equals(type) ? Color.GREEN : Color.YELLOW);
                }
                if (isRowSelected(row) && isColumnSelected(column)) {
                ((JComponent) c).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
                }*/
                return c;
            }
        };
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Remove all rows");
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
                    for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                        model.removeRow(i);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("model.getRowCount() --->" + model.getRowCount());
            }
        });
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Add new rows");
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Object[] data0 = {"Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50)};
                model.addRow(data0);
                Object[] data1 = {"Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25)};
                model.addRow(data1);
                Object[] data2 = {"Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35)};
                model.addRow(data2);
                Object[] data3 = {"Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00)};
                model.addRow(data3);
                System.out.println("model.getRowCount() --->" + model.getRowCount());
            }
        });
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel.add(button1);
        southPanel.add(button2);
        add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RemoveAddRows frame = new RemoveAddRows();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1329572: mKorbel's solution is the correct one (1+), but yours was viable too. I was up-voting it when you deleted it. :(

Comment: Yeah mKorbels solution is definitely cool to see for someone like me, user1329572 was easier to understand for someone like me but im gonna spend some time looking through mKorbels code to see about implementing my solution from it. Thanks both of you.